# Is possible to make fade animation between images in Ionic 2

Tags: css, typescript, animation, ionic2

as I searched about the animations of Ionic 2. I found some animations but not as I want.

I want to make animation like "fade" between Images. For example, I have 5 images and after 2 seconds the current image changes to other with fade animation.

I could did the half of work by using "setinterval" to repeat my code and change my images one by one after 2 seconds but I don't know if I can to make fade animation or not!

This is a sample example for my code (HTML + TS + Sample Gif Image)

**HTML**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <img src="imgs/{{variables.imageName}}.jpg">
</ion-content>
```

**TS**

```
export class HomePage {
   variables={
       imageName:"image1"
   }

  public loop1;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      this.loop1 = setInterval(() => {
          this.changeImage();
      }, 2000);
  }

  changeImage(){
      if(this.variables.imageName=="image1"){
          this.variables.imageName="image2";
      }
      else if(this.variables.imageName=="image2"){
          this.variables.imageName="image3";
      }
      else if(this.variables.imageName=="image3"){
          this.variables.imageName="image1";
      }
   }
}
```

**Result (I want to make fade between them)**

[image]

Comment: you can do that wiith javascript

Comment: @Ashishsah ok, I will search about that - may be I could find any thing can solve my problem

Comment: Why dont you hide the Image at certain Interval and just use jquery ```.fadeIn()``` method

Comment: Could you please add the most relevant parts of the code, so we can create a plunker with it? Using jQuey in Ionic is not a good approach. Instead, you could use just plain css or the Angular animation API.

Comment: @sebaferreras ok, few minutes and I will edit my question with sample example of my code

Comment: @sebaferreras Now u can see my codes and result, wish there is any way to make fade animation between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could find the solution [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/), but I'm not sure how can I implement it in Ionic 2

(I will edit this post if I got my wanted result)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/t3m5jngt/) :)

I used `fadeIn()` and `fadeout()` method in `jquery`. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but can I fadeIn the second image with the same time of fading-out the first image ?

Comment: So you want, when a first image fades out, the second image comes in directly?

Comment: yes, like the second image show in front of the first

Comment: I think, because of the delay transition time then when the time it fades out. But try to adjust the time transition if you want